# NVIDIA USB Type-C port policy controller keeps waking my PC up

Tags: windows-10, usb, sleep, power-management

My Laptop (HP Omen 15, Windows 10) is driving me crazy by turning itself on from sleep mode on its own. If I put it to sleep with the power button, it will often turn on again after about 3 seconds, or sometimes later (e.g. 1h or even several hours). If I leave it in sleep mode overnight, it will turn on and off multiple times.

What I have tried:

- Disabled all wake timers (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1162958/how-to-disable-wake-timer))
- Disabled "allow this device to wake the computer" for every single device in Device Manager
- Removed the wireless mouse and turned off touchpad -> no difference

This is what I see in command prompt:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg/lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg/waketimers
Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 04:00:00 on 瀀娤ú.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg -devicequery wake_armed
NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller
```

My understanding is that **NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller** is the culprit. I have obviously unticked the "allow this device to wake the computer" box in Device Manager for this device. Alas, if I restart the PC, the tick reappears!

My wish would be for the PC to only turn on if I press the power button. I don't want any other options. Any ideas, e.g. how to stop that tick from reappearing? Or could that wake timer be to blame (I thought that I had disabled all of them, but maybe not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good research and preparation; you've really done most of the work needed to answer your own question! The key line is `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed`.

As [Microsoft states](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080213-00/?p=23473), you should be able to use the following to disable the port from waking the PC:

```
powercfg -devicedisablewake "NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller"
```

That said, it might have a negative effect, e.g., preventing wake-up from a mouse or keyboard in that port, but can be reversed with:

```
powercfg -deviceEnableWake "NVIDIA USB Type-C Port Policy Controller"
```

See [S64](https://ss64.com/nt/powercfg.html) for more on *powercfg*.